# How can I accelerate the array assignment in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to make array assignment in python, but it is very slow, is there any way to accelerate?

```
simi_matrix_img = np.zeros((len(annot), len(annot)), dtype='float16')
for i in range(len(annot)):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        score = 0
        times = 0
        if i != j:
            x_idx = [p1 for (p1, q1) in enumerate(annot[i]) if np.abs(q1 - 1) < 1e-5]
            y_idx = [p2 for (p2, q2) in enumerate(annot[j]) if np.abs(q2 - 1) < 1e-5]

            for idx in itertools.product(x_idx, y_idx):
                score += simi_matrix_word[idx]
                times += 1
            simi_matrix_img[i, j] = score/times
        else:
            simi_matrix_img[i, j] = 1.0
```

"annot" is a numpy array. Is there any way to accelerate it?

Comment: Why are you trying to make array assignment? This is a supported feature..

Comment: I don't understand what the code is supposed to do. Could you show an example input and the corresponding desired output?

Comment: I want to get a similar matrix of images"simi_matrix_img"，where each element of the matrix is computed by "annot"([[1,0,1..],[0,1,1,...]]) and "simi_matrix_word[[-0.5,0.2,...], [0.3, -0.2, ...]]"; firstly, I must find the position of "1" in every two vectors of annot, put them in "x_idx" and "y_idx", then compute similarity of these 2 vectors by finding their values in "simi_martrix_word", lastly, get the  mean value of these values

Comment: What's the shape of `annot`?

Comment: @hpaulj, shape of annot is (4000,260), and it is a sparse matrix with 0 and 1

Comment: `dtype=int`?  `x_idx` is indexes of the 1s in the ith row?  Have you tried `np.nonzero`?

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure np.nonzero will save more time, I think the main computation is on the size of annot, and the loops consume much time

Comment: Got to start some where. Vectorize the inner loops.  Then you have a chance at doing the same for the outer ones.

Comment: You'll get more help if you provide small sample arrays, such that we can cut-n-paste a working script.  It is much easier to test and suggest improvements if we have a working example to start with.  We are lazy and don't like to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the indent for this line is wrong:

```
            simi_matrix_img[i, j] = score/times
```

you want to perform that assignment after all the `product` iterations.  But since it's the last assignment that takes, the results will be the same.

Here's a partial reworking of your code

```
def foo1(annot, simi_matrix_word):
    N = annot.shape[0]
    simi_matrix_img = np.zeros((N,N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            if i != j:
                x_idx = np.nonzero(annot[i])[0]
                y_idx = np.nonzero(annot[j])[0]
                idx = np.ix_(x_idx, y_idx)
                # print(idx, simi_matrix_word[idx])
                score = simi_matrix_word[idx].mean()
                simi_matrix_img[i, j] = score
            else:
                simi_matrix_img[i, j] = 1.0
    return simi_matrix_img
```

For a small test case, it returns the same thing:

```
annot=np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,1]])
simi_matrix_word = np.arange(12, dtype=float).reshape(3,4)
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 7.  1.]]
```

That gets rid of all the inner iterations. Next step would be reduce the outer iterations.  For example start with `np.eye(N)`, and just iterate on the lower tri indices:

```
In [169]: np.eye(2)
Out[169]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])

In [170]: np.tril_indices(2,-1)
Out[170]: (array([1]), array([0]))
```

Note that for a 2 row `annot`, we are only calculating one `score`, at `[1,0]`.

---

Replacing `nonzero` with boolean indexing:

```
def foo3(annot, simi_matrix_word):
    N = annot.shape[0]
    A = annot.astype(bool)
    simi_matrix_img = np.eye(N,dtype=float)
    for i,j in zip(*np.tril_indices(N,-1)):
        score = simi_matrix_word[A[i],:][:,A[j]]
        simi_matrix_img[i, j] = score.mean()
    return simi_matrix_img
```

or this might speed up the indexing a bit:

```
def foo4(annot, simi_matrix_word):
    N = annot.shape[0]
    A = annot.astype(bool)
    simi_matrix_img = np.eye(N,dtype=float)
    for i in range(1,N):
        x = simi_matrix_word[A[i],:]
        for j in range(i):
            score = x[:,A[j]]
            simi_matrix_img[i, j] = score.mean()
    return simi_matrix_img
```

Since the number of nonzero values for each row of `annot` can differ, the number of terms that are summed for each `score` also differs.  That strongly suggests that further vectorization is impossible.

Comment: thank you! that's a amazing, it solved my problem and I updated the original code with correct indent. Is boolean indexing more efficient than np.nonzero?

Answer (score 1):

(1) You could use generators instead of list comprehension where possible.  For example:

```
        x_idx = (p1 for (p1, q1) in enumerate(annot[i]) if np.abs(q1 - 1) < 1e-5)
        y_idx = (p2 for (p2, q2) in enumerate(annot[j]) if np.abs(q2 - 1) < 1e-5)
```

With this, you iterate only once over those items (in `for idx in itertools.product(x_idx, y_idx)`), as opposed to twice (once for constructing the list then again in said `for` loop).

(2) What Python are you using?  If <3, I have a hunch that a significant part of the problem is you're using `range()`, which can be expensive in connection with really large ranges (as I'm assuming you're using here).  In Python 2.7, `range()` actually constructs lists (not so in Python 3), which can be an expensive operation.  Try achieving the same result using a simple `while` loop.  For example, instead of `for i in range(len(annot))`, do:

```
i=0
while i < len(annot):
    ... do stuff with i ...
    i += 1
```

(3) Why call `len(annot)` so many times?  It doesn't seem like you're mutating `annot`.  Although `len(annot)` is a fast O you could store the length in a var, e.g.,  `annot_len = len(annot)`, and then just reference that.  Wouldn't scrape much off though, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank your for your help, (2) and (3) are very helpful, but I have a questions about (1): I get the position of  "1" by 
`x_idx = [p1 for (p1, q1) in enumerate(annot[i]) if np.abs(q1 - 1) < 1e-5]`
such as [0,3,5], so is y_idx [1,5,10], and then I want to get the combination of these 2 list by `itertools.product(x_idx, y_idx)`, which will generate (0,1),(3,1),(5,1),(0,5),(3,5),(3,10)..., if I use generator, how can I get these combinations?

Comment: Looking at the docs, it seems that `itertools.product()` accepts any iterable, including generators such as the ones I've suggested above.  So I believe all you need to do is change your list comprehensions to generator expressions and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, generator improves the efficiency of inner loop, but I think improve the efficiency of outer loop is more significant